# Get the length of words in a sentence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have large number of business names stored in our database. Some of our customers entered SSN into the names..i am trying to get all those business names

The Problem:

Find the length of each word in the NAME and return anyone that has a length of 9 or 11

Example :

1. test 123456789 test2 -- this should show up in the result
2. test 123456 test2--- this should not show up
3. test 123456789 test2 12345678911 -- this should show up

Any word in the string(numbers, or alphabets or combination of both) which is either 9 or 11 should be returned..thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: thank @hcaelxxam it solved my problem..sorry if i asked for the code because i didn't know where to start, my idea was to split the string into words and then check the length for each word which would taken way longer..

Answer (score 3):

You could just use LIKE.  Percent signs to ignore anything before or after in the column name, spaces to ensure that there is a space before and after, and then a range search for numeric values.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Table
WHERE
  Name LIKE '% [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %'
  OR Name LIKE '% [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %'
```

EDIT:

Actually, rereading the initial problem, it looks like you were not looking for only numeric strings of 9 or 11, but all strings.  In that case @JoeMalpass may have been more right that I thought.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  Table
WHERE
  --Surrounded by spaces
  Name LIKE '% [^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ] %'
  OR Name LIKE '% [^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ] %'
  --At the beginning with extra information after
  OR Name LIKE '[^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ] %'
  OR Name LIKE '[^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ] %'
  --At the beginning with extra information before
  OR Name LIKE '% [^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ]'
  OR Name LIKE '% [^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ]'
  --The entire column
  OR Name LIKE '[^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ]'
  OR Name LIKE '[^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ][^ ]'
```

Comment: You should also include versions that begin or end with the substring (repeat the clause without the `% ` at the beginning / ` %` at the end).

Comment: He could also just remove the spaces since % includes nothing, but fair point.

Comment: Removing the spaces would then allow for any substring longer than 9/11 characters though...

Comment: Very true, but we don't know enough about @showri's problem to know if either is desirable.  From what he said, it sounds like this is user input data, so it may make since to look for BusinessName123456789OtherInfo, or It may not be.  Regardless though, I think we're both right.